# How to find the surface area of $\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is the intersection of two paraboloids

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

The two paraboloids are: $S_1=\{(x,y,z)|z=2(x-1)^2+2y^2\},S_2=\{(x,y,z)|z=(x-1)^2+y^2+1\}$

Usually for me  to find the surface area I try to parametrize the surface and calculate it's normal vector $\vec{n}$ to find the area by the integral $\iint_D{||\vec{n}||}$,where $D$ is the projection of the surface on the $xy$ plane.

But i can't seem to find out what $\sigma$ is here,I have found the projection of $\sigma$ on the $xy$ plane to be $D=\{(x,y,y)|(x-1)^2+y^2=1\}$ by simply substituting $z$ from $S_1$ into the $z$ of $S_2$.

I need some clarity on how to find the parameterization or the function that describes $\sigma$.

Comment: The intersection of the two paraboloids is just the circumference you found. It has no surface!

Comment: I'm a bit confused because I'm asked to find an "Area" here ,how will this work ?